# HTML link <a> text wrapping breaking its border

Tags: html, css, css-float, anchor, word-wrap

Trying to write my first website for my new business I came across a problem that I can't work out.

I have a header with 2 `<div>`, 1 floated left and one right. The left-hand one contains links, while the right-hand one contains the page's title.

The problem is one of the links breaks in the middle, as you can see here:

[image: header pic]

This is my code:

```css
.links {
  max-width: 60%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin: 1% 4.5%;
  clear: left;
}

.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1%;
}

.links a:hover  {
  background:lightblue;
}

.FMS {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5%;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav class="links">
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>Service</a>
    <a>Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="FMS">TITLE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MonkeyNuts Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 0):

You should add [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to those `a` elements in order to prevent them from breaking after a space:

```css
#header {
  background: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.links  {
  width: 380px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin: 1% 4.5%;
  clear: left;
}

.title {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5%;
  clear: right;
  font-size: 2.2em;
}

.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.links a:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav class="links">
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>Service</a>
    <a>Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</header>
```

You can also use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to do that, but then they will remain `inline` elements, which do not respect vertical margins and paddings, while `inline-block` and `block` do, as you can see here:

```css
#header {
  background: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.links  {
  width: 380px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin: 1% 4.5%;
  clear: left;
}

.title {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5%;
  clear: right;
  font-size: 2.2em;
}

.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.links a:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav class="links">
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>Service</a>
    <a>Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="title">TITLE</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This code

1. HTML

   ```
   <div class="main">
     <div class="left">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">A</a>
      <a href="#">B</a>
      <a href="#">C</a>
      <a href="#">D</a>
      <a href="#">E</a>
      <a href="#">F</a>
     </div>
     <div class="right">
     logo
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. CSS

   ```
   .main{

     width:100%;
   }
   .left{
     width:70%;
    float: left;
   }
   .right{
     width:30%;
      float: right;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following CSS:

```
.link{
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  margin: 1% 4.5%;
  clear: left;
}
.link a { 
 text-docoration: none;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 1%;
}
.FMS {
 overflow:auto;
 margin: 0 5%;
 clear: right;
}
```

In .link div, use width: 60% instead of max-width: 60%. Then use overflow: auto in the FMS div. The overflow: auto in .FMS should cause the .FMS class to fill the remaining space available. If you want the content of the FMS div to be along the right border, then use float: right on the content rather than on the div.
You could also switch this, specify a specific width for FMS and then use overflow:auto for the .link div. The order in which the divs appear might matter when using this method. This might not be the answer you are looking for, but I thought I would suggest it.